# Add a Class and style to a dropdownlist rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have this code

```
 <%= f.select "banker_assignment[banker_assignment_status_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@banker_assignment_statuses, :id, :assignment_status, @banker_assignment.banker_assignment_status.id),  data: { selected: @banker_assignment.banker_assignment_status.id }, { :class => 'form-control single-select' }, { :style => 'float: right' } %>
```

I want to add the following class and style to the dropdownlist but i always get an error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...'form-control single-select' }, { :style => 'float: right' }...
...                               ^
```

How do i get rid of this error?

Thanks

Comment: Try this `<%= f.select "banker_assignment[banker_assignment_status_id]", 
options_from_collection_for_select(@banker_assignment_statuses, :id, :assignment_status, 
@banker_assignment.banker_assignment_status.id),  
data: { selected: @banker_assignment.banker_assignment_status.id }, 
{ :class => 'form-control single-select', :style => 'float: right' } %>`

Comment: still d same error.@Sontya  `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
...> 'background-color: white' } );@output_buffer.safe_append='
...                               ^
/home/k1ngsley/Projects/crm/app/views/lp_banker_assignments/edit.html.erb:213: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'; end`

Comment: you are already passing selected value in `@banker_assignment.banker_assignment_status.id` to `options_from_collection_for_select` and again why as `data`?